# Linked list toArray Java

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

How would I go about converting a linked list of integers to an array without using the built-in toArray method? I need to convert a sorted linked list to an array for a school project. I have the linked list part completed, and I just can not figure out how to convert this to an array. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Think of what you need. You must be able to iterate over your linked list and grab the values. So you need:

- an array the size of the list (does your list have a way to get that or to help create it?)
- a for loop to iterate over the list.
- a way of placing the value in the list in the corresponding location of the array.

Comment: I've got a size counter, and it accurately keeps track of the size. I just can't figure out how to add the data from the list into the array now.

Comment: If presume you can iterate thru the list so you can get the value and print it (otherwise, it isn't much use). So just do that and as you grab each value indexed by some variable, assign it to an array. Have you ever copied one array to another? It's the same operation.